# MySQL SELECT between two columns the higher id regardless of the field order

Tags: mysql

MyTable

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | name1 | name2 |
+----+-------+-------+
| 1  | foo   | bar   |
| 2  | bar   | foo   |
| 3  | alpha | beta  |
| 4  | foo   | alpha |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Now I want this back:

Result

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | name1 | name2 |
+----+-------+-------+
| 2  | bar   | foo   |
| 4  | foo   | alpha |
+----+-------+-------+
```

I search foo in the table.
If a match is found between name1 and name2 regardless of the field order then the highest id is kept.

I have tried but I have a problem to verify + don't have duplicate on the two columns

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE name1 = 'foo'
OR name2 = 'foo'
AND ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable GROUP BY name1) 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: So row 1 isnt selected because has `foo` but row 4 also has `foo` on name 1 with higer id?

Comment: yes but foo/bar=bar/foo and not foo/alpha

Comment: That is a different rule, so what is it? show the highest row with foo on name1 + highest row with foo on name2?

Comment: So row ID 2 is selected because it's the highest one with `bar` and row ID 4 is selected because it's the highest one with `foo` (or `alpha`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from MyTable t 
where not exitst
   (select * 
    from MyTable t2 
    where t.ID < t2.ID 
      and (t.name1 = t2.name2 OR t.name2 = t2.name1)
  )
```